Which bit do you use for cutting veneer grade plywood
I'm having trouble with rough edges and getting the rims correct is there a better bit to use and is there a recommended rpm setting

A spiral bit could be better than a straight one for mitigating rough edges (upcut, downcut or combined — depending on the cut your are making)

@stanch In this case, I'd say push that thin veneer down.  I keep forgetting if that's an upcut or a downcut.  Also how do you tell if the bit is upcut or downcut by looking at it.

It should be pushed towards the substrate, which could be above or below, depending on how the piece is oriented :) If the veneer is on top, then a downcut bit in the router or an upcut bit in the router table. And vice versa. This image shows the difference: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0510/5215/0961/files/img_v3_0297_c757c4d6-d5c0-4391-b437-4e3692a574dg.jpg?v=1711090371

A better bit would be something sharper, perhaps a new bit if the current bit has seen a bit of previous use. The question does not indicate what type of router bit cut is being done.
As for the veneer grade plywood, a year ago tearout wouldn't have been as bad as I've seen on current veneer-grade plywood. The older stuff had a thicker veneer. The recent veneer-grade plywood I've come across recently has extremely thin veneer.
Two things I've done when dealing with modern very thin veneer plywood are:

Score the line prior to routing. This will help a lot with chipping, however, it's impractical for things like drawer dovetails cut with a router.
Use a piece of scrap as a backer board. This is what I do with a Leigh dovetail jig. I clamp a bit of scrap board in front of the veneered board.

